# to be to and if-clause

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following sentence is given

> What would you do if I were to lose my job??

I would like to undestand the meaning of `were to`. Does it mean "upcoming event", that's I'll lost my job later in the future.

Comment: Consider: _"What **will** you do if I **lose** my job?"; "What **would** you do if I **lost** my job?"; "What **would** you do if I **was/were** to lose my job?"_

Comment: @F.E. The thing is your second and third examples have the same meaning for me. I think they talk about imagine situation, but the first asks about condition: What will you do in the case I lose the job.

Comment: @F.E. I seems I'm beginning to understand. The deffernce between the second and the third is the second ask about losing the job, but the the third is about you've not a job at all. Right?

Comment: Your first comment is more on target. The 1st version (with "will" and "lose") is merely talking about a hypothetical possibility (i.e. *open conditional*) of the speaker losing his job. The 2nd and 3rd versions (*remote conditionals*) are treating that possibility of actually losing a job to be rather unlikely (in the speaker's opinion, that is). Actually, there's not really any significant difference in meaning between the #2 and #3 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the future subjunctive. The subjunctive is a grammatical mood found in many languages. Subjunctive forms of verbs are typically used to express various states of unreality such as wish, emotion, possibility, judgment, opinion, necessity, or action that has not yet occurred – the precise situations in which they are used vary from language to language.  See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English

Answer (score 1):

The clause in question is "if I were to" - "to be to" by itself doesn't carry any meaning as far as I know.

It's basically the same as "What would you do if I lost my job", with an emphasis on the fact that it's a hypothetical, unlikely situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here "were to" is a present unreal conditional. We often use this like for example,

> If she were to be rich, she would be horribly obnoxious.

and,

> If Nathan were to be my boss, this job would be intolerable.

[**USE:**](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/wereto.html)

"Were to" can be used in the present to emphasize that the conditional form is very *unlikely*.